# Cannot find hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate.. Iam using netbeans IDE and i setup every thing.. I placed all my stuff(configuration and mapping files) into a package called **myfirsthibernate** while running the sample application it is showing the error as couldn't find the file **hibernate.cfg.xml**. But it is there in **myfirsthibernate** package. How to rectify this and why this is happening??

Please help me and thanks..

Answer (score 3):

By default, the hibernate.cfg.xml file is placed in /src/java/resource (which is in classpath by default directory). Could you please try placing the cfg file there?

Could you also give me some more info about the directory structure of your project.

Comment: src->myfirsthibernate->hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: directory: `src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml`

Comment: It still not found in my case, I use netbeans and Windows as OS

Answer (score 1):

The hibernate.cfg.xml needs to be in your classpath as well. Maybe write an ant task that automates this copying for you. Also, see [hibernate.cfg.xml not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196370/hibernate-cfg-xml-not-found) .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your project structure looks something like this `src>myfirsthibernate>[some files]`, the [Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-xmlconfig) says hibernate expects to find the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file at the root of the classpath by default. So in order to start hibernate like this

`SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();`

your directory structure should look like this

```
>src
   >myfirsthibernate
      >[your entity classes and mapping files here]
   >hibernate.cfg.xml
```

If you wish to keep the file under `myfirsthibernate` package, then you need to add it's location during the configuration :

`SessionFactory sf = new Configuration()
    .configure("myfirsthibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml")
    .buildSessionFactory();`