# Hibernate program in Intellij not able to run

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

This is the error I receive when executing my Hibernate program

```
Jul 02, 2015 6:07:12 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Jul 02, 2015 6:07:12 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final}
Jul 02, 2015 6:07:12 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jul 02, 2015 6:07:12 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jul 02, 2015 6:07:12 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Jul 02, 2015 6:07:12 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2005)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1986)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1966)
    at com.jlcindia.hibernate.Client.main(Client.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am not sure what is my problem, but this is what I have:

My `hibernate.cfg.xml` file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">1234</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping resource="com/jlcindia/hibernate/Author.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The `Author.hbm.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >

<!-- ${Example for "COLLECTION MAPPING" } -->

<hibernate-mapping package="com.jlcindia.hibernate">

    <class name="Author" table="jlcauthors">

        <id name="authorId" column="authorId" type="int">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>

        <property name="authorName"/>
        <property name="designation"/>

        <list name="emails" table="emails">
            <key column="authorId"/>
            <index column="myIndex"/>
            <element column="emailId" type="string"/>
        </list>

        <bag name="qualifications" table="qualifications">
            <key column="authorId"/>
            <element column="qualification" type="string"/>
        </bag>

        <map name="phones" table="phones">
            <key column="authorId"/>
            <index column="ptype" type="string"/>
            <element column="phoneNo" type="long"/>
        </map>

        <set name="books" table="books">
            <key column="authorId"/>
            <element column="bookName" type="string"/>
        </set>

        <array name="publications" table="publications">
            <key column="authorId"/>
            <index/>
            <element column="publications" type="string"/>
        </array>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The `Client.java` code:

```
package com.jlcindia.hibernate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Transaction tx=null;

        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                    configuration.configure();

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                    configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            tx=session.beginTransaction();

            List<String> ems=new ArrayList<String>();
            ems.add("aa@jlc.com");
            ems.add("bb@jlc.com");

            Map<String,Long> phs=new HashMap<String,Long>();
            phs.put("Off",new Long(111));
            phs.put("Hou",new Long(222));

            Set<String> bks=new HashSet<String>();
            bks.add("Learn Java");
            bks.add("Learn JDBC");

            List<String> qus=new ArrayList<String>();
            qus.add("M.Sc");
            qus.add("B.Sc");

            String[] pbs={"JLC1","JLC2"};

            Author a=new Author("sri",ems,phs,bks,qus,pbs,"S.E");
            session.save(a);

            tx.commit();
            session.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(tx!=null){
                tx.rollback();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. If I am missing any details or you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't type in all caps and please have a read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Duplicate with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196370/hibernate-cfg-xml-not-found

Comment: Is your hibernate.cfg.xml file in the `src` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [hibernate.cfg.xml not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196370/hibernate-cfg-xml-not-found):

> Your `hibernate.cfg.xml` needs to be inside the `src` directory; otherwise it's not covered by Ant's `copymetafiles` target, so it won't end up in your compiled classpath.